# Laravel: Multiple routes with same location and name

Tags: laravel, routes

In my laravel(7.x) application, I am trying to bind two routes `admin/` and `admin/dashboard` with same name. While running the `php artisan route:list` command, I am getting an error that `Unable to prepare route [admin/dasboard] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [admin.dashboard].`

Web.php

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'admin' ], function() {
    ...

    /**
     * Dashboard
     */
    Route::get('/', 'Backend\DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('/dasboard', 'Backend\DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

It was working fine in the previous versions of laravel.

How to fix this..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using **named routes** i.e. `->name(admin.dashboard)` twice but **named route must be unique** that is why you are getting error

```
 Route::get('/', 'Backend\DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
 Route::get('/dasboard', 'Backend\DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
```

To solve this change any one of your route to something else for e.g

```
Route::get('/', 'Backend\DashboardController@index')->name('admin'); // changed admin.dashboard to admin
Route::get('/dasboard', 'Backend\DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
```

Comment: Isn't there a way around, like passing an array, such as: `Route::get(['/','/dashboard'], 'Backend\DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');..?

Comment: You can use `namespace` routing `Route::namespace("Admin")->prefix("admin")->name("admin.")->group(function(){
   Route::get("/", "Backend\DashboardController@index")->name("dashboard");
   Route::get("/dashboard", "Backend\DashboardController@index")->name("dashboard");
});`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you ***@Sehdev***...

Here is the final code that I am using. Although, even with both routes mentioned in the `web.php`, you can only see the route in the browser, that is written at end, which in my case is `/dashboard`. However, both (`/`, `/dashboard`) route are working now.

```php
Route::namespace('Backend')->prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    ...

    /**
     * Dashboard
     */
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

Many thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two routes with the same names.

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'admin' ], function() {
    ...

    /**
     * Dashboard
     */
    Route::get('/', 'Backend\DashboardController@index')->name('home.dashboard');
    Route::get('/dasboard', 'Backend\DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```